# Automated detection of Sinkholes

Tags: filling, sink

I'd like to create a map of sinkholes in ArcGis 10, I have a DEM, 2m resolution, is there a tool to detect local minimum points ? tried "sink" tool without any success, result is very small holes.

And I did a fill to a certain depth, and substracted it frome the original DEM, it worked but not as precise as I want and lots of artefacts, very small holes, so I need to find a way to define to what extent (diameter, depth) holes need to be filled and I did not find that for now. can you help me ?

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to include the GIS software (and version) that you are using to try and do this, please?

Comment: You're almost there. Define the minimum depth difference, ignore those, and then convert to polygon and remove by area.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by sinkhole as well? Are you talking about the geologic phenomenon? Because those range significantly in size and are not always apparent from surface topography (in fact, they usually aren't and only are if they're a particular type). The tags you have used (and tools referred to) relate more to hydrology and flow of water. Is that what you are working on? Because the proper term there is sink - no 'hole' required.

Comment: Thanks Michael Miles, what do you mean by convert to polygon ? how do I do that ? Chris W: I mean karst sinkholes yes. The sinkholes I want to detect are defined between 10m and 100m in diameter and at least 0.3m deep. (this has been defined by a geologist knowing the area).

Comment: The goal is just a cartography of sinkholes in a specific area, and later on compare them to existing tectonic faults, no real hydrology study, but I also tried hydrology tools as flow accumulation/direction as those would indicate sinkholes when converging in one close point, but I was not successful with delimiting contours with these tools

Comment: It looks like you have at least one of your values. Any difference less than 0.3m you ignore, as for converting to polygon that is software dependent (see PolyGeos' original comment). I might say that karst isn't as easy to find as sinks because they're not very deep. In my case I was looking for dry lakes (plenty of them in Australia) that may be holding water, I was able to get around 90% accuracy using this method. Unless the features you're trying to locate are *clearly different* you're not going to get 100% accuracy using automated processes.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson thanks, it sounds like this methodology will work for my case too! it's stupid but I still can't figure out how I set a minimum depth difference, is that done with a different tool or by changing parameters in the fill tool ? in which case I don't know the name, tried to change almost everything, like M values, Z... without any change in filling depth

Comment: Perhaps Extract by Attributes where Value > 0.3 http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000029000000 - this will give you a new raster that contains only values greater than 0.3. Then using IsNull find where the output raster (> 0.3) is/isn't null, this binary raster is great for raster to polygon, just be aware you will have the whole area covered with polygons with grid_code of 0 (non-null) and 1 (null). Remove the grid_code = 1 from the polygons then calculate area, clean out the small ones and you're done. I hope at the end of this you can answer your own question.